# What kind of small plastic device has two spikes protruding from the end?

Tags: tools

A friend found a few of these in a toolbox. The two metal prongs are sharper than they appear in this pic, and are not connected inside in any way.

Does anyone know what they are?

[image]

[image]

Comment: my friend opened one up and said they look just like flathead nails inside the plastic casing.

Comment: Did the toolbox have any 2 part epoxy in it?

Comment: This may be a bit outside the scope of "Home Improvement."  Try asking on https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/

Comment: we also thought spacer but why the need for nails?

Comment: It's probably a key to a toilet paper dispenser.

Comment: @Hotlicks may have the right of it: some kind of spanner driver. It isn't electronic, or even electric.

Comment: Find its mate, and yer all set fer eatin' corn-on-the-cob.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a spacer for installing tile or flooring with a uniform gap?